# Cross Domain Post - Losing POST Data

Tags: xml, iis-7, post, iis-6, msxml

I have 2 servers, both running R2 / IIS7 / ASP Classic sites (can't get around any of that)

Server A is making the follow calls:

```
Dim objXMLHTTP, xml
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXmlHTTP.6.0")

xml.Open "POST", templateName, false
xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
xml.Send variables
```

Where the templateName is the URL of Server B (It's an email template)
... and variables are a name value pair string like a query string password=myPassword&customerEmail=Dear+Bob,....

Server B receives the POST but all the POST data (password=myPassword&customerEmail=Dear+Bob,....) is missing from the POST

```
password = Request.Form("Password")
customerEmail = Request.Form("CustomerEmail")
```

The above values are all empty.

Here's the kicker. This all worked on our old servers (Windows Server 2003, IIS 6)

But when we migrated over, this stopped working correctly.

My question is:

What would cause the POST data to be dropped in IIS 7 when it all worked in IIS 6?
I've done about 3 days of research into this trying many different things and nothing has worked.

The POST data is just gone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Content-Type declaration.  It specifies that the post data is XML and not name/value pairs.

```
xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
```

You should use this instead...

```
xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application x-www-form-urlencoded"
```